# Transparent background like in spotlight search

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

How to make transparent background for the whole application?
I have such settings for the main view:

[image: settings]

But I still get non transperent background on the device

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: open the spotlight search on your iphone and you will see exact the same what I want

Comment: You want it to show the iphone's background?  I'm not sure that is possible

Comment: Something like that. Why not?

Comment: Because  it doesn't seem like something Apple would allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put a bgView behind your desired view(original view), Set your original view background to clear color. Make bgView background color black and set alpha as desired.

EDIT:

If you meant to make the whole app transparent and show the device wallpaper as bg, then I am pretty sure its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Transparency..

*) check Opaque off

*) change alpha depending on yur need.

Comment: didn't change transparency of the background.

Comment: alright try using code like this.

overlayView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];